# Does MySQL have a “print” function to show custom text output？

Tags: mysql, sql

I want MySQL outputting a sentence to describe the query results before outputting query results. How to do it?

For example, I want to write a procedure to query information about students with specific names，the name will be passed as argument to the procedure.
this is my snippet of my procedure :

```
delimiter $$
create procedure show_specific(in student_name text)
begin
declare b_count int default 0;
select count(*) into b_count from students where students.name=student_name;
if(b_count=0)
then select 'Not found';
else
select*
from students where students.name = student_name
end if;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

Maybe this is not a good example... In this example, if the b_count is zero, this procedure will output 'Not found'. I can use 'print' in SQL server. However MySQL doesn't have 'print' function, Is there similar function in MySQL?

Comment: whenever you ask a question like how do I do x in y like I can in z, remember that you are asking people who know something about y, not necessarily z, and say as much as you can about what x does in z.

Comment: FWIW: PRINT in SQL Server is always buffered and won’t write anything to the client before the batch is complete. In MSSQL it’s more customary to use RAISERROR..WITH NOWAIT to show diagnosis output. That is, using PRINT, the message *wouldn’t* be displayed before the query in the same batch. (https://sqlity.net/en/984/print-vs-raiserror/)

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you described why you want to do this.  I don't believe there is any completely equivalent feature in mysql.  You can return a warning that the client can see with `SHOW WARNINGS` by doing:

```
signal sqlstate '01000' set message_text='message to client';
```

Answer (score 0):

You just `select` it:

```
select 'hello world' as greetings
```